# How to send data to a page via Ajax and then see that data immediately?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So I know how to write ajax code I just don’t know how to use it in my project as far as the way the data flows and how the pages are structured. So I am building a to do app. I did in plain PHP with 1 list and the ability to add tasks. Now I’m trying to have multiple lists. And of course update the content based on which ever list is clicked. Here’s my code so far:

```
function ajax_Request(list){ 
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", 'index.php?name=' + list);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
             window.location.href = 'http://localhost:8888/index.php?name=' + list;

         }
    }
}
```

The data is sent via GET but it gets erased when I redirect to the page so idk how to think about it. I encountered the similar problem with a previous Quiz App.

Comment: It sounds like you need to read up on how to change the text on a page using JavaScript.  Like setting the .innerHTML value of a span or div - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: Oh no it's not text its data from a database I’m trying to show based on which ever list is clicked.

Comment: If that data isn't text, what is it?

Comment: You'll need to format it so it can post as HTML. Either do this in JS or call a PHP page that formats it and returns to Ajax the formatted HTML to shove into the `div` you want.